# Ring of polynomials in infinitely many variables

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I am reading wiki article on polynomial rings and I want to make sure that I understand the bit about generalization allowing infinitely many variables. Let
\begin{equation}
A=\mathbb{Z}[x_i|1\leq i \leq \infty]
\end{equation}
be the ring in infinitely many variables $x_i$. Each polynomial is a linear combination of monomials of finite degree with all but finitely many coefficients equal to $0$. Therefore, given any polynomial $p \in A$, there exists $m \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $p \in \mathbb{Z}[x_i|1\leq i \leq m]$. Thus, things like $x_1x_3^4 + 3 x_7^2x_{\infty}^7 \notin A$ (or is this false?). Suppose we want to generalize $A$ further. Let
\begin{equation}
A^{'}=Z[x_i|1 \leq i \leq \infty]
\end{equation}
be the ring of finite formal power series in infinitely many variables $x_i$. All the monomials are again of finite degree. Does $x_1x_3^4 + 3 x_7^2x_{\infty}^7 \in A^{'}$? To summarize, is the polynomial ring in infinitely many variables essentially the same as the ring of finite formal power series in infinitely many variables (based on the assumption that all monomials in both rings are of finite degree)?

Comment: I can't say I much like the idea of labelling a variable as $x_\infty$. Seems quite unnecessary and excessive to me.

Comment: What do you mean by $x_{\infty}$? Is there just another variable called $x_{\infty}$ or are you trying to refer to some kind of "limit variable"? (There is no "limit variable.")

Answer (score 1):

Since $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}\cup{\infty}$ are equipollent, "adding" a variable $x_\infty$ changes nothing.

Every single polynomial in no matter how many variables can be written using a finite amount of them. Thus
$$
R[x_1,x_2,x_3,...]=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}R[x_1, ...,x_n].
$$
For power series the situation is different. Let $\zeta_n=x_2\cdots x_n$. Then
$$
F(\underline{x})=1+x_1+\zeta_2x_1^2+\zeta_3x_1^3+\cdots
$$
is a formal series that cannot be written using only finitely many variables.